# How can I grep a file using OR

Tags: linux, grep

I want to search a file with either this string 'foo' or this string 'bar'. This is what I've attempted so far:

```
cat filename.csv | grep foo\|bar
```

Comment: just use single quotes `cat filename.csv | grep 'foo\|bar'`

Answer (score 3):

You can specify multiple patterns with multiple `-e` flags:

```
grep -e foo -e bar filename.csv
```

This is a POSIX standard.

Answer (score 1):

What I suggested earlier does not work on some installations.  I believe this is a more portable syntax:

`grep -E 'foo|bar' filename.csv`

The above is an alternative form of:

`egrep 'foo|bar' filename.csv`

egrep supports use of a regular expression, which in this case is 'foo|bar'

Comment: If my answer worked for you, please upvote or accept it as I would like to earn reputation

Answer (score 0):

Use [egrep](https://ss64.com/bash/egrep.html) with a regex.

```
cat filename.csv | egrep 'foo|bar'
```

Comment: `egrep` is deprecated in favor of `grep -E` and `cat file | grep ..` is a UUOC.

Answer (score -1):

You can use any of following.

> *cat filename.csv | grep -E 'foo|bar'*
>
> *grep -E 'foo|bar' filename.csv*

Comment: this is a duplicate of the existing answers.